# WPF disable default keybinding on DataGrid (as if it was never defined)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, key-bindings

I would like to disable some of the default behaviours of `DataGrid` keys in order to override it with my own improved commands. How can I disable `DataGrid`'s keybinds as if they were never defined in the first place?
For example, `Enter` key jumps to new row by default, I would like to focus item detail control instead. Stopping the event is easy enough with `this.handled = true;` that, however also prevents any custom `Command`s from happening, minimal example of the problem:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Model {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestCommand : ICommand {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
        public void Execute(object parameter) => MessageBox.Show("Command invoked");
    }

    public ICommand EnterCommand { get; } = new TestCommand();
    public IEnumerable<Model> Items {
        get { return new List<Model>() {
                new Model { Name = "Foo", Value = 15 },
                new Model { Name = "Bar", Value = 1 },
                new Model { Name = "Baz", Value = 42 },
                new Model { Name = "Bar", Value = 100 } }; }
    }

    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) e.Handled = true;
    }
}

//MainWindow.xaml, Window.Name = "Root"
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding EnterCommand, ElementName=Root}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=Root}" PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

When `Enter` key is pressed while DataGrid is focused, `EnterCommand` should be invoked via `<KeyBinding/>` i.e. **without explicit reference** in codebehind (ViewModel ommited for brewity) and DataGrid's default behaviour prevented, i.e. not jumping to next row.

Comment: Obviously you can't disable key bindings "as if they were never defined in the first place". They *are* defined and the code that creates them *does* get executed. What you can do is to override or disable specific behaviours, but you can't "disable" the framework code from being executed.

Comment: @mm8 true, I would like to override keybindings in a way that could be described as in the quote "as if they were never defined in the first place". It is not important whether it actually unsubscribes from something, what is important it acts as desired (last question paragraph).

Comment: You can't use key bindings here without first write some code in the the code-behind, a custom control or in a behaviour.

Comment: @mm8 The keybinding is defind in sample code in xaml (`<Window.InputBindings>`). Custom one which should be executed, while the default one should not. I am aware it would require some code to achive that and well... which code it might be is the question here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could programmatically raise another `KeyDownEvent` event once you have handled the `DataGrid`'s `PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(this), 0, Key.Enter)
        {
            RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
        });
    }
}
```